# How to properly compare two dates of Gregorian calendar on main function

Tags: java

I recently started to work with Java, I'm following a webtutorial and I just faced this error:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field c1 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field c2
```

The code I was applying:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class TestsCalendar {
    Calendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar(2005, Calendar.OCTOBER, 12);
    Calendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar(2005, Calendar.OCTOBER, 13);

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(c1.after(c2)); } }
```

Whats is the right way to write this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the main method is static, it means it is not tied to any instance of your class. In order for the fields `c1` and `c2` to be accessible without static, there needs to be an instance of the class:

```
TestsCalender cal = new TestsCalendar();
// access cal.c1 now
```

Do note, that with your currently posted code, `c1` and `c2` will actually not be made into objects ("constructed") until you actually create that new TestsCalendar instance.

Alternatively, if it's a small program, you can just mark the fields themselves static:

```
static Calendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar(2005, Calendar.OCTOBER, 13);
```